# Auto generate strong password in Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, app-site-association

I am really struggling to get the **Generate Strong Password** - Function done inside ma app...

This is my website: `https://wishlists-app.de/` . I already set up **Associated Domains** and **Autofill Credential Provider** inside my app like this:

[image]

I think that's all I need to do on my App's site, right? I know I have to do something with **Apple-App-Site-Association** but this is the part where I struggle and can't find any good tutorial...

I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/developerinsider/ios12-password-autofill-automatic-strong-password-and-security-code-autofill-6e7db8da1810) but I have no idea how to realize the 2nd step. I have no idea how exactly I have to create this `Json-File` and "add" it to my website. My provider is [all-inkl.com](http://all-inkl.com). The tutorial isn't very "newbie"-friendly on this nor is the Apple-Documentation, so I hope someone can help me out here.

And is there something else I need to do? I already set all the `textField.textContentType` but right now when selecting the `passwordTextField` Xcode is telling me this:

> Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID:
>   com.ckbusiness.Wishlists due to error: Cannot save passwords for this
>   app. Make sure you have set up Associated Domains for your app and
>   AutoFill Passwords is enabled in Settings

Does adding the `Association-File` fix this issue or is there something else to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Via the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html):

> Adding support for universal links is easy. There are three steps you
>   need to take:
>
> - Create an apple-app-site-association file that contains JSON data about the URLs that your app can handle.
> - Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your HTTPS web server. You can place the file at the root of your server or in the
>     .well-known subdirectory. Prepare your app to handle universal links.
> - Prepare your app to handle universal links.

*easy* is Apples description. Not mine.

You need to get the correctly formatted `apple-app-site-association` file (that's the exact name) uploaded to your web directory at preferably a sub-folder called `.well-known`. That's the first place iOS will look, the root is the second place iOS will look. The file **MUST** be served via `https`.

Comment: I've read that as well. But: What exactly does "JSON data about the URLs that your app can handle." mean? And how do I `upload/place` that file to my server ? Like I said in the question I know my things around Swift but when it come to Web-development I am a complete beginner..

Comment: Your website appears to be hosted by Wordpress. That’s a different problem and might require you to change your hosting package to achieve this. Here’s a related question which might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390443/config-apple-app-site-association-file-with-wordpress/45399792#45399792