# Upload file Bitnami Wordpress to .well-known served through application/json

Tags: ios, wordpress, bitnami, ios-universal-links

I just start using Bitnami Wordpress for Apache and I am having trouble implementing Password Autofill for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

In a nutshell, a file called `apple-app-site-association` should be available from a `.well-known` dir on a domain:

```
https://<fully qualified domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

**served with `application/json`**

The thing is, that almost every tutorial I come across has been outdated. Take [Config apple-app-site-association file with WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390443/config-apple-app-site-association-file-with-wordpress) for example. They are talking about paths like `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl`, but I don't have a `/etc/apache` dir.

I am connected to the server over SFTP. I see that my root dir is `/home/bitname/`. Inside that, I see a `stack` dir which contains the wordpress dir. I upload a file to this dir and I can download it instantly from my domain. But when I create a new `.well-known` dir and put the file inside there, I can not reach this following domain:

`https://<fully qualified domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

I restarted Apache like this:

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

And it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I had to put the file in `/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/.well-known/` since bitnami's letsencrypt httpd conf moves the `.well-known` directory outside of `htdocs`.